# disadvantages of ccache

Tags: performance, gcc, compilation, ccache

I am using ccache for experiments, but I am not quite sure that I should use this. Can anyone explain the situation when ccache can result in wrong behavior. Or should we always use ccache ? Anyone who got that ccache is producing wrong object files or changes in header files are not being considered ?

Comment: http://ccache.samba.org/ says that there shouldn't be any wrong behavior, and that if someone knows of one, he should report it instead of answering questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: absolutely. thanks, I should use updated ccache and keep looking for existing reported bugs which are not being handled to stay aware of might-be bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I practically never have any issues while using `ccache`. Sometimes (e.g. once a month or even less), I clean entirely its cache with `ccache -C`.

I have more issues with complex *Makefile*-s than with `ccache`.

To be short, don't bother, and when you suspect something, just run  `ccache -C`.

You obviously should avoid `ccache`  when you are benchmarking the compilation time. (You could pass `-time` or `-ftime-report` to `gcc` or `g++` in that case).

#### Addenda

I my opinion, `ccache` should be at least configurable to disable caching for compilation using GCC plugins, because a GCC plugin could do anything (e.g. querying a database or webservice) which is not cachable. See [this message](https://lists.samba.org/archive/ccache/2012q4/001011.html).

Comment: thanks for suggestion... :-). btw what the situations when you get issues sometimes ? because when we get issues it is difficult to get clue that it's coming because of ccache. and also when you get issues, "ccache -c" is the absolute solution, then there must be some problem with ccache.

Comment: No, I strongly suspect the hypothetical issues to be in Makefile-s. In MELT http://gcc-melt.org/ my Makefile-s are buggy (and GCC Makefile-s are perhaps incomplete also for partial rebuilds). Again, I never suspected ccache of doing wrong.

Comment: `ccache` being usually fired as `gcc` if a bad `Makefile` forgets to run a compilation command, with or without `ccache`  you get in trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You phrased your question well by asking wrong **behavior**.

The wrong behavior ccache may have is slowing down your compilation if used incorrectly. ccache has to scan the file to recognize past compilations, so an actual compilation through ccache is slower than without it. Only a cache hit is faster.

ccache is useful when you frequently recompile the same code without modifying it. It will not speed up compilation of new or modified code.

Answer (score 3):

I once had issues with SCons compiling through ccache (symlink method).

#### Environment Settings

It turned out ccache *requires* the $HOME variable to be set in the environment, whereas SCons doesn't set it by default (SCons has the policy to isolate builds from the environment as much as possible by default).

I'm not entirely sure whether this would count as a problem with ccache or merely interoperating with SCons. Besides this quirk, I never had any trouble with ccache.

#### SSD wear

I have adopted the habit of linking ~/.ccache to tmpfs to avoid wearing my SSDs unnecessarily. Obviously, this is not a problem with ccache, because without it, things would be worse still. (*Just something to keep in mind*)